# Send a byte via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wanted to know how to send a byte in binary form via bluetooth.
At the moment I use this code:

```
mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
     }
});
```

only in this way sends string and not a byte.

Thanks for the help.

This is the source:

```
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the source for the `sendMessage` method?

Comment: @Juan-devtopia.coop here is the source

Answer (score 0):

According to your source code, you are sending byte array already with the `write` method. If you called `mChatService.write(byte[]data)` so calling something like this, should work:

```
mChatService.write(new byte[]{5});
```

Where `5` is the byte value you want to send, in other words, the call to the `sendMessage` method is only translating your String into a byte array which is then sent to the bluetooth service.

Comment: However, in this way arrive up to 127, right? how do I send an 8-bit binary number like this '11001100 '?